# Get the Checkboxlist value when unchecked Client-Side

Tags: jquery, asp.net

How to get the value of Checkboxlist value when item is unchecked? I tried the following code but I am not getting the value.  Please let me know.

```
JQuery
----------------

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=chkboxTypeList.ClientID%> input[type=checkbox]").click(function () {

            if (!this.checked) {
               alert($(this).val());
            }

        });

.aspx
-------------------
                        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkboxTypeList" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="TEST 1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="TEST 2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="TEST 3" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values of `checkboxlist` are stored in `Viewstate` and not rendered clientside.

One way of getting the value client side is using a `Attribute`.

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkboxTypeList" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
     <asp:ListItem Text="TEST 1" Value="1" ClientValue="1"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="TEST 2" Value="2" ClientValue="2"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="TEST 3" Value="3" ClientValue="3"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

This is then rendered like:-

```
<td>
  <span clientvalue="2">
    <input id="chklstStates_1" type="checkbox" name="chklstStates$1">
    <label for="chklstStates_1">TEST 2</label>
  </span>
</td>
```

Then use:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#<%=chkboxTypeList.ClientID%> input[type=checkbox]").change(function () {

        var value = $(this).parent().attr('clientvalue');

        if (!this.checked) {
           alert(value);
        }

    });
});
```